# Initialize two fields at once with Lombok builder

Tags: java, lombok

I'm trying to populate two fields in a class by using only one field in a Lombok builder.

e.g.

```
@Builder
public class Foo {
   @NonNull
   private final double bar1;

   @NonNull
   private final double bar2;

}
```

I want

```
Foo.builder().bar1(0.0).build();
```

to also set bar2 to the same value as bar1.

Thanks

Comment: But why? What is the motive? You can very well use `Foo.builder().bar1(0.0).bar2(0.0).build();`

Comment: I have an existing class Foo with only bar1. I wanted to add the bar2 field without changing all the uses of Foo and adding the additional bar2, since it'd be the same value.

Comment: @Jason can you inherit the Foo class and do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually implement the setter method in the builder class such that it sets both fields:

```
@Builder
public class Foo {
   @NonNull
   private final double bar1;

   @NonNull
   private final double bar2;

   public static class FooBuilder {
       public FooBuilder bar1(double bar1) {
           this.bar1 = this.bar2 = bar1;
           return this;
       }
   }
}
```

The rest of the builder code will still be generated by Lombok. You'll just have to write those methods you want to replace.

However, I'm not sure if this is worth it: `Foo.builder().bar1(1).bar2(2).build()` will have a different result than `Foo.builder().bar2(2).bar1(1).build()`. This could introduce bugs that are very difficult to spot. At least make sure you document it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Nice thought, but lombok `@builder` does not support that. You have to assign values individually. You can see your compiled class which will make you clear what code lombok generates after compilation.

However, if you really want to initialize two fields at once, you would need to implement your own builder pattern.